# quick sort python implementation

Tags: python, arrays, quicksort

```
def quicksort(a,start,end):
    if(start<end):
        #print(start,end)
        p_index = partition(a,start,end)
        quicksort(a,start,p_index-1)
        quicksort(a,p_index+1,end)

def partition(a,start,end):
    pivot = a[end]
    pindex = start
    for i in range(start,end):
        if (a[i]<= pivot):
            a[pindex],a[i]=a[i],a[pindex]
            pindex = pindex+1
    a[pindex],a[pivot]=a[pivot],a[pindex]
    print(pindex)
    return pindex

a = [7,6,5,0]
quicksort(a,0,3)
print(a)
```

this implementation is giving out the wrong output. Correct me where I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in your `partition` function where you swap the pivot element into its final position is incorrect. `pivot` is the value of the pivot element, not its index. The index of the pivot at that point is still `end`.

Change:

```
a[pindex],a[pivot]=a[pivot],a[pindex]
```

to:

```
a[pindex],a[end]=a[end],a[pindex]
```

or maybe:

```
a[end] = a[pindex]  # we don't need to do a simultaneous swap because we already
a[pindex] = pivot   # have a separate reference to the value of the pivot element
```